# Android Studio - Change Button Background Color when Clicked

Tags: android, button, colors, click, state

I've got a Table with a lot of Buttons that act like checkboxes. As the title says, I want the background color of the Buttons to be changed when pressed (checked). I am attempting to do that by using 3 drawable resource files.

The first one is an oval with a white stroke, indicating the **default state** of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The second one is another oval with white fill, indicating the **pressed** state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Lastly, the third drawable xml file is the one I currently have set as the background of the buttons, and is used to switch between the previous 2 drawables, according to the Button's state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/table_option_fill" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/table_option_fill" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/table_option_border" />
</selector>
```

The switch between the drawable files when clicking the Buttons works fine. The problem is, the Button becomes white only **when clicked and held down**. Once I release it, it reverts to its normal state with the white stroke.

What I want is for the Button to become white and stay that way when I click it, and then to revert to the default state once I click it again, kind of like when toggling a switch.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use custom `ToggleButton`. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton) and [this](https://medium.com/@rashi.karanpuria/create-beautiful-toggle-buttons-in-android-64d299050dfb)

Comment: You can also maintain a boolean variable to toggle the state and update background accordingly.

Comment: I used `ToggleButton` and combined it with a boolean variable like you both mentioned, works perfectly. Thank you so much!